# Java Convert unixtime to date , giving wrong results

Tags: java, date, unix-timestamp

Im trying to convert unixtime to date but the results im getting are wrong :
for example i have this unixtime : 1354312800 accurding to this site :
[enter link description here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)
the result is :
Fri, 30 Nov 2012 22:00:00 GMT

but when i do :

```
long timestamp = 1354312800;
java.util.Date time=new java.util.Date((long)timestamp*1000);
int d = time.getDay();
int m = time.getMonth();
```

im getting :
d= 6  **<< this is wrong should be 30.**
and m - 11

Comment: By correcting the original post according to the answers, you're basically invalidating our answers (rolled back) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`Date.getDay()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay%28%29) gives the day of the *week* (0 = Sunday, ..., 6 = Saturday).

Change it to [`Date.getDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate%28%29) and you will get `30` as the result.

---

Some side-notes:

- The `Date` class is pretty much deprecated. Use `Calendar` instead, or even better, the [Joda time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net).
- Your conversion is sort of funny. `(long)timestamp*1000` converts `timestamp` to a long value (which *is* already a long value) and then automatically widens `1000` to a long value to carry out the multiplication.

  I would skip the conversion, `(long)` , altogether, and if you want to explicitly say that the factors are long values, use `1000L` instead, which is a long-literal.

Comment: how can it be , the result is 1 not 30 in my pc . 
mybe something to do with time zones?

Comment: Wow. That's really strange. The "current time" is not involved in the calculation. Did you paste the exact code from the link I posted?

Answer (score 4):

You have mistaken `getDay()`for `getDate()`.

getDay Javadoc:

> Returns the day of the week represented by this date. The returned value (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, 4 = Thursday, 5 = Friday, 6 = Saturday) represents the day of the week that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

So just use `getDate()` instead of `getDay()`

For more info, check the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

---

If your time still differs from the Unix time you tried, you are probably living not in the GMT Timezone, so you need to find out the date for the corresponding timezone:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(df.format(time));
```

This should give you the expected output, even though your local tiemzone differs from GMT

Comment: i fixed it in the original post , it still wrong gives me 1 and not 30

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the specifics on the timezone you are in.

Comment: How does the timezone affect which `Date` `1354312800*1000` corresponds to?

Comment: Because the time is `Fri, 30 Nov 2012 22:00:00 GMT`, and if he lives at e.g. GMT+4, it would be the first of december, so the `getDate` method would also return 1.